# php cURL request using modified headers

Tags: php, curl

I want to capture the response of a site (http://gnocchi-www.buffalo-ggn.net/bingo2-v2.47.0-JACKET/js/cache/static_desktop_data.json) in my php file to write the available collection items in a databse.

If I enter the adress in my browser, I get a json string as response. But If I use a cURL request, I get an empty response.

Here is my curl code:

```
$url = 'http://gnocchi-www.buffalo-ggn.net/bingo2-v2.47.0-JACKET/js/cache/static_desktop_data.json';
$headers = array( 
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        "Host: gnocchi-www.buffalo-ggn.net", 
        "Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4", 
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch", 
        "Accept: */*"
    ); 

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://gs1.wac.edgecastcdn.net/805F48/gnocchi/bingo2-v2.47.0-JACKET/assets/Game.swf");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response=curl_exec( $ch );
echo $response;
```

the headers that are sent when I enter the url in browser are:

> Host: gnocchi-www.buffalo-ggn.net
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>
> Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Can anyone help me with this problem ???

Comment: That exact code works for me - I get loads of JSON data (578604 bytes according to the returned `Content-Length` header). You get a few warnings for your code though - try turning on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see if you get some useful info out of it.

Comment: `CURLOPT_GET` option doesn't exists (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: thx Nils and hindmost.
On my other server it works fine. Dont really understand, but its working there. Thx for your help. Maybe I should have tried there before.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from your code:

```
"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch",
```

If you really want to send any encoding request, then Add this curl option with your code.

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
```

Finally, this one doesn't have any effect on the modern version of libcurl. So remove this one.

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
```

Comment: Thx Sabuj.
I removed them both, and it works like a charm on my other host.